# Can two different events generate the same set of probabilities?

Tags: probability

I have been thinking about the following problem: Consider set $\Omega$ of possible outcomes and the set $\mathcal{P}$ of all probability measures $p$ over the events from $\Omega$. Let us define $C=\{ p\in\mathcal{P}: p(E)=1  \} $ for some event $E\neq\emptyset$. My question is that would it be possible to get the same $C$ with different events, say $E\neq F$?

I tried contradiction to prove it is not possible. I used $1\geq p(E\cup F)=p(E)+p(F)-p(E\cap F)\geq 0$ which yield $p(E\cap F)=1$ and $p(E\cup F)=1$, however, I could not conclude that $E=F$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $E\neq F$, say $E\setminus F \neq \emptyset$, what happens to a probability measure $p$ such that $p(E\setminus F)>0$, say $p(E\setminus F)=1$? It will be in $C_E$, but cannot be in $C_F$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Without loss of generality, we may assume that there exists an $x\in E$ such that $x\notin F$. Let $p$ be the measure
$$
p(S)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\in S \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.
$$
Then $p(E)=1$ since $x\in E$, but $p(F)=0$ since $x\notin F$.